# How do I create a table to match based on different columns values ? If statements?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, filter

I have a dataset and I am looking to see if there is a way to match data based on col values.

```
  col-A    col-B      
  Apple    squash     
  Apple    lettuce    
  Banana   Carrot     
  Banana   Carrot 
  Banana   Carrot
  dragon   turnip 
  melon    potato
  melon    potato
  pear     potato
```

Match

- if col A matches another col a and col b doesn't match
- if col B matches another col B and col a doesn't match

```
col-A     col-B      
Apple    squash     
Apple    lettuce 
melon    potato
melon    potato
 pear    potato
```

edit fixed typo

edit2 fixed 2nd typo

Comment: Are you able to be more explicit about the criteria here? I'm sensing a pattern in your expected output but not enough to write a definite solution.

Comment: if col A matches another colA and col B doesn't match.  or if col-b matches another col b and col A doesn't match.  I wrote it in bullet points

Comment: What do you mean by "col A matches another colA" - can it be any "col A" or just the one coming immediately after?

Comment: i fixed the typo. sorry

Comment: @enke sorry i fixed the 2nd typo.  i am new at this sorry.  please i am learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand well, you want to select each rows, such that grouping for colA (resp. colB) then colB (resp. colA) lead to more than one group.

I can advice :

```
grA = df2.groupby("colA").filter(lambda x : x.groupby("colB").ngroups > 1)
grB = df2.groupby("colB").filter(lambda x : x.groupby("colA").ngroups > 1)
```

Leading to :

```
grA
    colA     colB
0  Apple   squash
1  Apple  lettuce
```

and

```
grB
    colA    colB
6  melon  potato
7  melon  potato
8   pear  potato
```

Merging the two dataframes will lead to the desired ouput.

Comment: thanks wow great solution

Comment: I find mozway's solution more elegant since it uses masks and not a lambda. Maybe more efficient also.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need to compute two masks to identify which group has a unique match with the other values:

```
m1 = df.groupby('col-B')['col-A'].transform('nunique').gt(1)
m2 = df.groupby('col-A')['col-B'].transform('nunique').gt(1)

out = df[m1|m2]
```

Output:

```
   col-A    col-B
0  Apple   squash
1  Apple  lettuce
6  melon   potato
7  melon   potato
8   pear   potato
```

You can also get the unique/exclusive pairs with:

```
df[~(m1|m2)]

    col-A    col-B
2  Banana   Carrot
3  Banana   Carrot
4  Banana   Carrot
5    Pear  Cabbage
```